# To be worse off for 'missing' or 'longing for' something

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, verbs

> The reader ____ a more concrete example of ...

In the same vein as "finds missing", how can I say the reader is left worse off for not being given a concrete example of [...]?

> The reader misses a more concrete example of ...

Although technically true in the sense of "yearning for", it's weird and doesn't have the connotation of dissatisfaction.

> The reader finds lacking a more concrete example of ...

Seems too accusative of the author, and too rational not as emotional as I would like.

Same meaning as "would appreciate", but specifically highlighting that it currently doesn't exist.

Comment: You mentioned "finds lacking"; what about "the reader *feels the lack of*"? A bit more feeling, but not as intense as yearning or pining.

Answer (score 1):

The OP says that *finds lacking* is "not as emotional as I would like."

> The reader **thirsts** for a more concrete example of...

thirst (v.)

> *Figurative*. To have a longing, craving, or strong desire. OED

---

> If, for example, in the story of Joshua Abbina's, told in chaper 3, the reader **thirsts** for detail, so does the
> historian. [Kenneth Stow; *Theater of Acculturation*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Theater_of_Acculturation/tSjECgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22The%20reader%20thirsts%20for%22&pg=PA7&printsec=frontcover)

> The reader **thirsts** for additional details that will flesh out the
> portrait. [Derek Harris; *The Spanish Avant-garde*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Spanish_Avant_garde/cQbpAAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22The%20reader%20thirsts%20for%22&pg=PA59&printsec=frontcover)

> This book, this beautiful wonderful book, is the precise manifestation
> of how one should go about the business of combing absolutely
> exhaustive research with a firm grip on the elements of narrative that
> the reader **thirsts** for when first lifting the book off its
> shelf... [Hubert O'Hearn; blurb for Charles Foran; *Mordecai*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Mordecai/C4FE2oyoAHkC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22The%20reader%20thirsts%20for%22&pg=PR3&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 0):

> The reader ____ a more concrete example of ...

*Craving* **n.**

- a strong desire for something

The reader *craving* a more concrete example of...

If you are trying to convey the same meaning of "would appreciate"

*Eager* **adj.**

- a keen desire or feeling of anticipation

> The reader *is eager for* a more concrete example of...